# In react native how do I change root view background color on Android?

Tags: react-native

I have read a couple of tutorials online but most of the talk of iOS or some talk of Android but using old versions of react, everything has changed now.

If I open MainActivity.java there's only one method

```
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myapp";
}
```

which means I can't access the rootview and change its background color because it seems even the onCreate method isn't available to anyone nowadays.

I also tried opening res/styles and adding my lines there but I keep getting errors

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

I tried that but nothing changes, still the same grayish background appears. 
Wish I could just do it in react but adding background there not only adds unnecessary overdraws, when loading there's this lag with one background then later changes to another, its very ugly.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MaximMcNair unfortunately no I haven't found any solution for it.

Comment: @MaximMcNair see my answer below

Answer (score 11):

In `android/app/src/main/res/values/`:

- Create (or edit) `colors.xml` to add your background color, e.g.:

```xml
<resources>
  <color name="background">#AB47BC</color>
</resources>
```

- In `styles.xml`, add a theme customization item named `android:windowBackground`, referencing the chosen color name, e.g.:

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a library, it allows you to do it from the level of JavaScript, and also allows you to do dynamic changes.

https://github.com/johniak/react-native-root-view-background

```
import { setRootViewBackgroundColor } from 'react-native-root-view-background';

export default class Main extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        setRootViewBackgroundColor('#ccc');
    }
}
```

The downside of this solution is that color is set after JS is loaded.

Comment: I would not install an third-party component for such an tiny adjustment. Make your live easier and minimize the usage of component to the amount you _really_ need

Answer (score 0):

you can change it through React native stack navigation.

```
      <RootStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
          contentStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
        }}
        initialRouteName={Routes.LOADING}>
        <RootStack.Screen
          name={Routes.LOADING}
          component={Screens.LoadingScreen}
        />
        <RootStack.Screen name={Routes.LOGIN} component={Screens.LoginScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen
          name={Routes.SIGN_UP}
          component={Screens.SignUpScreen}
        />
```

you need to modify your root view. like

```
contentStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to implement React styling to change the background color.

Comment: I know about react styling, I stated the reason why that's not a solution I want right now because it draws two different backgrounds, and if there's an animation or anything that brings lag, the root view background will show first then after a second the background I set on react. That's a very ugly experience