# React Native - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: react-native-web

I am new to react native and I am currently trying to implement react native web in my application. The problem is when I try to compile my web application this error is displayed:

uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (58:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
|   // otherwise, we're ready to render the app
|   return (
>     <ToggleStorybook>
|       <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
|         <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
```

It looks like this error is coming from my app/app.tsx file but I don’t know what could be creating this issue.

Here I am attaching my files.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname);
const {presets} = require(`${appDirectory}/babel.config.js`);

const compileNodeModules = [
  // Add every react-native package that needs compiling
  // 'react-native-gesture-handler',
].map((moduleName) => path.resolve(appDirectory, `node_modules/${moduleName}`));

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.js$|tsx/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.web.js'), // Entry to your application
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.tsx'), // Change this to your main App file
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    ...compileNodeModules,
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      presets,
      plugins: ['react-native-web'],
    },
  },
};

const svgLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: '@svgr/webpack',
    },
  ],
};

const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'index.web.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'rnw_blogpost.bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.web.tsx', '.web.ts', '.tsx', '.ts', '.web.js', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      babelLoaderConfiguration,
      imageLoaderConfiguration,
      svgLoaderConfiguration,
      
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // See: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/349
      __DEV__: JSON.stringify(true),
    }),
  ],
};
```

**index.web.js**

```js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import App from './app/app';
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
AppRegistry.runApplication(appName, {
  initialProps: {},
  rootTag: document.getElementById('app-root'),
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>RN Web</title>
    <style>
      #app-root {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 100%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.tsx**
This file is located inside another folder: app/app.tsx

```js
  // Kick off initial async loading actions, like loading fonts and RootStore
  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      await initFonts() // expo
      setupRootStore().then(setRootStore)
    })()
  }, [])

  // Before we show the app, we have to wait for our state to be ready.
  // In the meantime, don't render anything. This will be the background
  // color set in native by rootView's background color.
  // In iOS: application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
  // In Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45838109/204044
  // You can replace with your own loading component if you wish.
  if (!rootStore || !isNavigationStateRestored) return null

  // otherwise, we're ready to render the app
  return (
    <ToggleStorybook>
      <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
        <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
          <ErrorBoundary catchErrors={"always"}>
            <AppNavigator
              initialState={initialNavigationState}
              onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            />
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </RootStoreProvider>
    </ToggleStorybook>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: In your error, over the line `|   // otherwise, we're ready to render the app` it should appear another line telling you the package/file that is throwing that error, it would be easier to help if you add that

Comment: @CrsCaballero, thank you for taking a look at my question.
This is the full error that is throwing at me:

ERROR in ./app/app.tsx 58:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (58:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   // otherwise, we're ready to render the app
|   return (
>     <ToggleStorybook>
|       <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
|         <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
 @ ./index.web.js 1:241-261